# Koin - How to generify Singleton creation?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, singleton, koin

I have a class `InteractorCache<T>` that I would like to inject in different places using Koin.

I would like to create a singleton instance of that class based on the type `T`. So if I have 10 types `T`, I would like 10 different singletons.

So far I managed to do the above with the following code (this is an example with only 2 types, A and B):

```
val interactorAModule = module {
    factory {
        InteractorA(get())
    }
}

val aCache = module {
    single(named("A")){
        InteractorCache<List<A>>()
    }
}

val interactorBModule = module {
    factory {
        InteractorB(get())
    }
}

val bCache = module {
    single(named("B")){
        InteractorCache<List<B>>()
    }
}
```

This works but there is a lot of repetition as I have to create a new cache module (aCache, bCache) every time I create a new type. I would like to be able to do something like this instead:

```
val cacheModule = module{
     single<T>{
         InteractorCache<T>()
    }
}
```

so there is only 1 declaration that works for any type T.

Is there a way to do this in Koin?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is late but the idea of making generic or T a singleton is bad idea, when you declare a class singleton it will run a single instance, so runtime error would be InteractorCache() is incompatible or mismatched to InteractorCache() as the first class you would assign the T for example the class A InteractorCache() it would be fixed instance of A and cannot anymore assign to class B.